# FFMPEG Tiff images to losseless video (H265) lags, broken output

Tags: ffmpeg, compression

I have 226 sequenced images (TIFF, 6.2MB each) and i would like loseless save them like video by using H265.

Here is command which I used:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 25 -i IMG_%03d.tif -vcodec libx265 -x265-params lossless -strict experimental -pix_fmt yuv420p -report movie_newh265yuv420.mp4
```

And here is output video: [Broken Output Video](http://chmura.rarez.pl/index.php/s/kek6ZYzyDklfZjP)

I really don't know how to fix it. Video should looks like this one [Good Video](https://youtu.be/hFei6iaO4zo) If u have any idea I will be very glad.

Report from FFMPEG below:

Thank you

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7sMn1Vye - Report

Comment: You have 261 frames but only 226 frames have been encoded. 35 frames are missing. Cycle through the image sequence at slow speed in a image browser and see if the jumps still occur.

Comment: My bad, I have 226 frames so all have been encoded. Where is mistake now ? Maybe I should add something specific -x265-params ?

Comment: What do the image filenames look like?

Comment: IMG_001.tif to IMG_226.tif

Comment: Run `ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 25 -i IMG_%03d.tif -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p raw_newh265yuv420.avi` and see if the jumps occur.

Comment: The same :/ maybe something wrong with my ffmpeg ?

Comment: No. the files seem to be picked out of order. Scan through them manually to check continuity but take care to note the file being scanned.

Comment: I made mistake in change name script /facepalm. Now everything it's ok. Sorry mate for my brainless and Thank you so much for your perseverance